# DJANGO : Inlineformset specifying fields / exclude

Tags: django, django-forms

can i simply do this by

```
BusinessFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Address, Person, exclude = 'middlen')
```

what if not, please let me know how i should go about specifying which fields i want to render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#controlling-which-fields-are-used-with-fields-and-exclude

But:

```
BusinessFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Address, Person, exclude = ['middlen'])
```

exclude must be a iterable object like a list